# RapidMiner: Split attribute into bytes

Tags: split, rapidminer

I have a dataset with an attribute in the form of an ASCII string, the characters of which have their own meaning (e.g. given "L2A", "L", "2", and "A" each represent something different).

How do I split this string into its constituent characters? I know about "Split", but I'm not sure how to use it when there's no delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the source attribute is always the same then you can use the `Generate Attributes` operator to cut the string into pieces.

Here's an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.2.003">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="179" y="85">
    <list key="attribute_values">
      <parameter key="s1" value="&quot;ABC&quot;"/>
    </list>
    <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="179" y="187">
    <list key="attribute_values">
      <parameter key="s1" value="&quot;DEF&quot;"/>
    </list>
    <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="103" name="Append" width="90" x="380" y="85"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="514" y="85">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="att1" value="cut(s1, 0, 1)"/>
      <parameter key="att2" value="cut(s1, 1, 1)"/>
      <parameter key="att3" value="cut(s1,2,1)"/>
    </list>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

If the length varies, then it's a harder problem